# An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to > resolve service for type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple asp.net core web api and I am trying to consume just the api/values that comes by default with the visual studio template. however I get this error:

> Hosting environment: Production Content root path: C:\api.E-commerce
>   Now listening on: http://localhost:18401 Application started. Press
>   Ctrl+C to shut down. fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HL3RHG5NLHAL": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
>   resolve service for type
>   'ECommerce.Api.Repository.Ecommerce.IEcommerceRepository' while
>   attempting to activate 'ContactsApi.Controllers.ValuesController'.
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
>   sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.TypeActivatorCache.CreateInstance[TInstance](IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, Type implementationType)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(ControllerContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()

the startup code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ContactsApi.Contexts;
using ECommerce.Api.Models.ERP;
using ECommerce.Api.Repository.ERP;
using System.IO;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal;

namespace ContactsApi
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

           // var host = new WebHostBuilder()
           //.UseKestrel()
           //.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           //.UseIISIntegration() // IMPORTANT!!!
           //.UseStartup<Startup>()
           //.Build();
           // host.Run();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc()
                    .AddJsonOptions(a => a.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()); ;

            //using Dependency Injection
            //services.AddSingleton<IContactsRepository, ContactsRepository>();
            //services.AddSingleton<ITodoTerrenoRepository, TodoTerrenoRepository>();

            services.AddDbContext<ContactsContext>(options =>
             options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthentConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<TODOTERRENOContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders", builder => builder.AllowAnyHeader());
                options.AddPolicy("AllowCredentials", builder => builder.AllowCredentials());
            });

            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {

                options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
                options.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
                options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true;


            });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
            app.UseCors("AllowAllHeader");
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            //app.UseMvc(routes =>
            //{
            //    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //});           
            //// Shows UseCors with CorsPolicyBuilder.
            //app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

values controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using ECommerce.Api.Repository.Ecommerce;

namespace ContactsApi.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {

        public IEcommerceRepository ContactsRepo { get; set; }


        public ValuesController(IEcommerceRepository _repo)
        {
            ContactsRepo = _repo;
        }
        // GET api/values
       // [HttpGet]
        //public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        //{


        //    ContactsRepo.CrearUsuario();

        //    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        //}

       // [HttpGet]
        [HttpGet("{DatosUsuario}")]
        public string GestionarUsuario(string DatosUsuario)
        {



            return ContactsRepo.GestionarUsuario(DatosUsuario).Result;
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet]
       // public string Get(in)
        public string Get()
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**UDPATE 2**

Now we get Stackoverflow exception!, with no details at all in the log file

Comment: Could you show constructor of ValuesController?

Comment: please check the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you did not register ***EcommerceRepository*** to ***IEcommerceRepository***.

*For example,*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddTransient<IEcommerceRepository, EcommerceRepository>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Now I get a stackoverflowexception

Comment: You will need to set break points at Startup.cs and ValuesController's constructor, and debug step-by-step.

Answer (score 5):

The error messages indicates that the `ValuesController` is being hit. While trying to instantiate this controller the `IEcommerceRepository` is used in the constructor.
The dependency injection framework is trying to find an implementation of the type `IEcommerceRepository`.

This should be registered in the `Startup.cs`. You can register it something like:
`services.AddSingleton<IEcommerceRepository, MyEcommerceRepository>();` in the ConfigureServices method.